# How to connect a digital sensor through SPI

Tags: sensors, spi

I want to connect a ADXL355 development board accelerometer to an Arduino. I cant get any data form the sensor. The data_ready pin is never high and I can't read the registers. 
The connections ([user guide](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/EVAL-ADXL354-355-UG-1030.pdf)):[image]

I connected VDD and VDDIO to 5V, ground to ground, DRDY to the correct pin, CS, SCLK, MOSI and MISO all to correct pins.

Code:

```
//modeled on https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BarometricPressureSensor

#include <SPI.h>

const int ID = 0x00;
const int FIFO = 0x11;
const byte READ = 0b11111100;
const byte WRITE = 0b00000010;

const int dataReadyPin = 6;
const int chipSelectPin = 7;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    SPI.begin();

    // initalize the  data ready and chip select pins:
    pinMode(dataReadyPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(chipSelectPin, OUTPUT);

    delay(100);
    readRegister(ID);  
}

void loop() {
    if (digitalRead(dataReadyPin) == HIGH){
        Serial.println("data ready");
        delay(500);
    }    
}
void readRegister (byte thisRegister){
    byte inByte = 0 ;
    Serial.println(thisRegister, BIN);

    thisRegister = thisRegister<< 2;
    byte dataToSend = thisRegister & READ;
    Serial.println(thisRegister, BIN);
    digitalWrite(chipSelectPin, LOW);
    SPI.transfer(dataToSend);
    inByte = SPI.transfer(0x00);
    Serial.println("data: ");
    Serial.println(inByte);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're shifting your address too far.

- Read should be 0b00000001 not 0b00000010.
- Your address should be shifted one bit not two.

Also you need to turn it on. By default the device is in standby mode. You need to enable it by setting bit 0 of register 0x2D to 0.

---

```
byte readRegister (byte thisRegister){
    byte inByte = 0 ;
    digitalWrite(chipSelectPin, LOW);
    SPI.transfer((thisRegister << 1) | 1);
    inByte = SPI.transfer(0x00);
    digitalWrite(chipSelectPin, HIGH);
    return inByte;
}

void writeRegister (byte thisRegister, byte value){
    digitalWrite(chipSelectPin, LOW);
    SPI.transfer(thisRegister << 1);
    SPI.transfer(value);
    digitalWrite(chipSelectPin, HIGH);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I thought it should be shifted by 2 because of the tutorial I am following... While debugging, I connected the ground pin on the 3-pin group labelled standby to ground, and it shorted out. What is the group for?

Comment: "Standby or Measurement Mode Selection Pin. Set this pin to ground to enter standby mode, or set this pin
to VDDIO to enter measurement mode. " - should do something similar to bit 0 of register 0x2d, but inverted.